# Get string after specific word in C#

Tags: c#, .net, string

I have a string with this html:

```
<div class="cnt_listas"><ol id="listagem1" class="cols_2">
<li><a href="/laura-pausini/73280/">16/5/74</a></li>
<li><a href="/laura-pausini/73280/traducao.html">16/5/74</a></li>
</div>
```

I need to get all the text between `<ol id="listagem1" class="cols_2">` and `</div>`.
The text in this string can be different from that, it's a result of a website.
How can I get this part of the text?

In this case the text I need would be:

```
<li><a href="/laura-pausini/73280/">16/5/74</a></li>
<li><a href="/laura-pausini/73280/traducao.html">16/5/74</a></li>
```

Comment: Between what? And furthermore, what have you tried so far?

Comment: Come on search on HTML parser -1

Comment: Have you considered a proper HTML parsing library? Like the HtmlAgilityPack?

Answer (score 2):

I would use [HtmlAgilityPack](http://htmlagilitypack.codeplex.com/)   to parse html

```
HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument doc = new HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument();
doc.LoadHtml(html);

var h = doc.DocumentNode.SelectSingleNode("//ol[@id='listagem1']").InnerHtml;
```

Answer (score 0):

How about this code I found a few weeks ago on Stackoverflow while in need of the same algorithm?

```
private IEnumerable<string> GetSubStrings(string input, string start, string end)
{
    Regex r = new Regex(Regex.Escape(start) + "(.*?)" + Regex.Escape(end));
    MatchCollection matches = r.Matches(input);
    foreach (Match match in matches)
        yield return match.Groups[1].Value;
}
```

**EDIT:** [This](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2548406/796036) is the source of this code.

**EDIT 2:** To counter one comment on my answer, please have a look at [this](http://xkcd.com/208/).

Comment: Eeewwww Regex for HTML..

Comment: @SimonWhitehead: I have left you a note in my answer.

Comment: and how do I work with the returned value? IEnumerable<string> Can I just convert it to string?

Comment: @LeandroAbilio: How about `List<string> results = resultEnumerable.ToList();` or `string[] results = resultEnumerable.Cast<string>().ToArray();`? This will return a collection with all occurences.

Answer (score 0):

Not really the best way to parse HTML, but here's an extension method that will generically work on strings in the way you are asking:

```
public static string Between(this string source, string start, string end)
{
    // Find the first occurence of the start string
    var i = source.IndexOf(start);
    if (i < 0)
        return string.Empty;

    // Advance past the start string
    i += start.Length;

    // Find the next occurence of the end string
    var j = source.IndexOf(end, i);
    if (j < 0)
        return string.Empty;

    // Return the string found between the positions
    return source.Substring(i, j - i);
}
```

Put it in a static class and then call it like this:

```
var substring = s.Between("foo","bar");
```

Manipulate as needed for edge cases (string not found, etc)

Answer (score -1):

I don't get exactly what you are saying... maybe this:

```
string specificWord = stringWhtml.Substring(stringWhtml.IndexOf("cols_2") + 8, stringWhtml.IndexOf("</div>"));
```